# how can i deploy a project only for Windows pc not for Mac pc in flex?

Tags: apache-flex

I want to deploy my project only for windows os not for Mac pc. The application is build up with flex. How can i deploy this only for window pc?

Comment: Why would you want to do that?  The benefit of using the Flash Platform is easy cross platform deployment.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can force the projector to compile into a a specific OS.

The best answer I can provide is to limit your app, by detecting the OS and causing a popup and disabling your app.

```
var operatingSystem:String = Capabilities.os;
trace(operatingSystem);
```

Etc.. "Windows XP", "Mac OS 10.x.x", "Linux"

That'd be set to only work on any OS you choose.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so you can force.

> When you deploy your application, you
>   make it available to customers.
>   Typically, you deploy the application
>   as a SWF file on a web server so that
>   users can access it by using an HTTP
>   request to the SWF file.

You can restrict to certain users or domain through crossdomain.xml